# iPhone - pushing and pulling a value from a dictionary to a CGlayer

Tags: iphone, quartz-graphics, cglayer

I have a finger painting view that I am implementing undo/redo. All the drawing occurs on a CGLayer called lineLayer.

As soon as the user touches the screen but before any modification is done to the screen, I need to quickly grab the views content and create an undo level.

Obviously saving the view to disk is not an option, because it takes too long. The solution I imagined is to copy the CGLayer to a dictionary, using something like this:

```
// I copy the layer as a NSValue
NSValue *layerCopy = [NSValue valueWithBytes:&myLayer objCType:@encode(CGLayerRef)];
```

I store it on a dictionary

```
NSString *aKey = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [number intValue]];
[self.dictUNDO setObject:layerCopy forKey:aKey];
```

later I retrieve it using

```
NSString *myKey = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [number intValue]];
NSValue *myCopy = [self.dictUNDO objectForKey:myKey]; 
[myCopy getValue:&lineLayer];
//lineLayer is the CGLayer where the drawing happens
```

the problem is that lineLayer is not changed at all by this reading operation. 
It continues to have the same contents as before.

Am I missing something?

thanks.

Comment: HI RubberDuck, did you succeed in your approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered Core data for managing your objects? I'm asking because Undo/redo comes for free with it?

Comment: the problem would be the same. If I cannot retrieve a CGLayer from a dictionary I won't from a core data. I have already the Undo(redo working for other things, but not for this CGlayer. Apparently it is saving on the dictionary but not retrieving.

Comment: You're right, I misunderstood question. I can't think of solution but two alternatives come to mind though. One is to create new CAlayer for each user action and when undo threshold is exceeded (let's say 10 steps back) grab thos layers below threshold and render them into one. Another soluTion could be using core data to store actions in form of states and render all actions during drawRect onto single layer. This might be doable but I'm not sure about performance.

Comment: @Digital Robot Another option is to subclass CALayer and use CGContextSaveGState/CGContextRestoreGState CGContext functions.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to do a deep copy, like creating a bitmap context from the layer?

Comment: can you post some example of how do I do that?

Comment: can you be more specific? the page has one mile of length and trillion lines of code... thanks.

Comment: search 'deep copy' and you will get it (the only match).